# bin/rails sするとspringがすでにロードされているというエラーが解決できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

#### エラーの内容

タイトルの通りRailsのプロジェクト内で`bin/rails s`を実行すると下記のようなエラーが発生します。

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.3.1 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
You've tried to invoke Spring when it's already loaded (i.e. the Spring constant is defined).

This is probably because you generated binstubs with Spring 1.0, and you now have a Spring version > 1.0 on your system. To solve this, upgrade your bundle to the latest Spring version and then run `bundle exec spring binstub --all` to regenerate your binstubs. This is a one-time step necessary to upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1.

Here's the backtrace:

/Users/name/Project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `load'
/Users/name/Project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `block in load'
/Users/name/Project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/Users/name/Project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `load'
/Users/name/Project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/name/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/namen/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/name/Project_name/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

#### 試したこと

- エラーメッセージで言われていることを実施しました

  - `bin/spring binstub --remove --all`をした後に
  - `bundle update spring`を実施し、`bundle exec spring binstub --all`を実施
- mac自体の再起動

  - プロセスのリセット
- vender/bundleを削除して、`bundle install`してgemの入れ直し
- `bundle exec rails s`をすると毎回異なるエラーが発生する

```
/Users/name/Project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require':
 cannot load such file -- action_view/template/types (LoadError)

とか

/Users/name/Project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/i18n-1.8.9/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:245:in `rescue in load_yml':
 can not load translations from /Users/name/Project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/faker-2.16.0/lib/locales/en/final_space.yml:
 #<Errno::EINTR: Interrupted system call @ rb_sysopen - /Users/name/Project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/faker-2.16.0/lib/locales/en/final_space.yml> (I18n::InvalidLocaleData)

とか

/Users/name/Project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/psych-3.3.0/lib/psych.rb:581:in `initialize':
 Interrupted system call @ rb_sysopen - /Users/name/Project_name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/faker-2.16.0/lib/locales/en/final_space.yml (Errno::EINTR)

など
```

#### 分からないこと

エラーの解決方法も分からないのですが、
そもそもエラーの内容にあるspringのバージョン1.0や1.1に身に覚えがなく、
自分のプロジェクト内のspringのバージョンは、2.1.1であり、自身のローカルに入っているspringのバージョンも2.1.1です。

```
❯ bin/spring -v
Spring version 2.1.1

❯ spring -v
Spring version 2.1.1
```

どなたか解決方法が思いつく方、何かわかりそうな方力を貸していただけるとうれしいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: springを削除してみるのはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 「いろいろやったらいろいろエラーがでます」では問題が絞り込めないので、「どういう手順で操作したらどういうエラーが出た」を整理したらよいと思います。

Comment: Big Surにアップグレードしたことが原因だったみたいです。コメントくださったかたありがとうございました。